# Drawing an entire image in triangle in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I am drawing triangle portion of the image using

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleImage.png"];
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,10.0f, 200.0f); 
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,200.0f,10.0f); 
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,200.0f,200.0f);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,200.0f,200.0f);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path); 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor); 
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path); 
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, flipVertical); 
    CGContextClip(ctx);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(10, 10.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f), image.CGImage);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
```

But i need entire image to be mapped into the triangle region. Is it possible to achieve this using core graphics?

Comment: do you mean you need the top corners of the image to touch the 2 oblic sides of the triangle? (assuming that the base of triangle is horizontal and the corner is above)

Comment: I mean if the change the co-ordinates of the triangle, the image must also modify according to new set of points (like skewing)

Comment: so you have an image, and you need to crop it into a triangle, then use the new image (that actually is a transparent rectangle, with a triangle image on it) did I get you right?

Comment: for example, after cropping a image to triangle, if i change the angle of triangle means the image also should change according to triangle. i.e., i need to map image co-ordinates into the triangle

Comment: post, please the original image, the image cropped into the triangle, and the triangle after changing it's angle. you could do it in GIMP or whatever image editor. I doubt I understood you right, I still cannot get what do you wanna achieve